# Create 64-bit value from datetime object

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, datetime

I'm working with pulling information out of Active Directory which means I'm dealing with some COMObjects. One of them has a date that is stored as a 64-bit integer (which is actually two 32-bit ints). I've figured out how to change it into a datetime object by using the following code.

```
def convert_to_datetime(time_object):
    # http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/html/com/help/active_directory.html
    d = 116444736000000000L #diference between 1601 and 1970
    time_int = (((long(time_object.highpart) << 32) + long(time_object.lowpart)) - d)/10000000
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_int)
```

Now with this in place I'm wanting to build a unit test for this. However, I can't seem to figure out how to generate a 64-bit integer from a datetime object. What I am doing currently is I have created a class to replicate a COMObject, which stores its value as two 32-bit integers, and then hard-coded the values for the date and integer that match. However, I would like something that creates these values based on the time of "right now".

Here is what the unit test looks like currently, which passes.

```
    def test_convert_to_datetime_for_64bit_int_returns_value(self):
        now_com_time = COMObjectDate(30375774,216380170)
        self.assertEqual(datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 3, 14, 0, 13), AD_AG.convert_to_datetime(now_com_time))

class COMObjectDate:
    def __init__(self, high, low):
        self.highpart = high
        self.lowpart = low
```

Is there a way to generate the two 32-bit values from a datetime object?

*Side note:* I realize I may be over thinking this some since my unit test does pass but I would prefer to not have hard-coded values so that the tests are stronger and not reliant on values that "just work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll start with a quote from the documentation you linked to:

> Time in active directory is stored in a 64 bit integer that keeps
>   track of the number of 100-nanosecond intervals which have passed
>   since January 1, 1601.

So consider the parts as two 32 bit integers (high and low, leading zeroes added):

```
bin(30375774) =

00000001110011110111111101011110

bin(216380170) = 

00001100111001011011001100001010
```

Join them together (the 'high part' and the 'low part') to get the 64 bit integer:

```
0000000111001111011111110101111000001100111001011011001100001010
```

In decimal, that is `130462956137067274`.

To get the number of **seconds** passed since the 1st of january 1601, we'll have to divide by
`10000000`.

```
130462956137067274 / 10000000 
= 13.046.295.613 seconds since the 1st of january 1601
```

Simple date arithmetic should get you the reverse should you wish to construct the corresponding 32 bit integer parts: start from the number of seconds since the 1st of january 1601, multiply by 10000000 and split the 64 bit integer in it's two 32 bit parts (which can be done easily by bit shifting).

The `convert_to_datetime` method implementation should make sense too. The only thing you'll need to now is that the `datetime.fromtimestamp()` method expects a [POSIX timestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp), which is a float (in this case) that contains the number of seconds elapsed since `epoch` (the 1st of january 1970). This explains the offset based calculation present in the method body.

```
====> 1. Creating a Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) from a datetime
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())
1401828155.0 

====> 2. Adding the difference in seconds between 01/01/1601 and 01/01/1970 
====> (11644473600 seconds)
>>> 11644473600 + 1401828155
13046301755

====> 3. Multiply by 10000000
>>> 13046301755 * 10000000
130463017550000000

====> 4. Interpret as binary. Add leading zero's until you have 64 bits.
>>> bin(130463017550000000)
'0b111001111011111110110110001011001011001001010111110000000'

====> 5. Split the high part (32 bits) and the low part (32 bits)
>>> ...
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to work the math backwards! That was dumb of me. I can tell this is the right direction. However, I'm stuck on the part of splitting it into the high and low (which at this revision I'm guessing you might be too).

Comment: You can do that easily by bit shifting (as stated in the answer) :) Here's the details: to get the 'high' part: `bin(130463017550000000 >> 32)`. To get the low part: `bin(130463017550000000 & 0x00000000ffffffff)`. Ps the bin is not needed but clearly shows what the bit shift (and logical and) does.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was missing. Only discovered bitwise operations yesterday so I'm still trying to figure them out.

Comment: If you have a mental picture of 64 bits lined up it's actually pretty simple. `>> 32` shift *all* bits 32 positions (to the right). You'll get 32 'new' zeroes on the left (coming in), and you'll lose the 'low' part (they get shifted 'out'). The 'high' bits are at the low part after the shift, ready for interpretation as a 32 bit number. For getting the 'low' part we only need to get rid of the 'high' part (zero that out). To do that, we do a logical and with a hex representation of 32 zeroes followed by 32 ones. The first 32 bits will now be zero --> the low part remains :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the addition should come after the multiplication. So it should be `(seconds * 10000000) + 11644473600`. At least that is what I'm getting when I work the formula backwards.

Comment: It all depends on unit. If your difference between 1601 and 1970 is in seconds (like in the samples above), the logic above is correct. Your logic is fine if you're using the 100-nanosecond intervals (like the `convert_to_datetime` method is using). What it would look like then is : `(seconds * 10000000) + 116444736000000000L` (notice the extra zeroes). The distributive property of multiplication :)